# dll built on vs2005 differently on different machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, msbuild

I'm building a dll(c# assembly which implements some interfaces) that's called by another app. the dll built on my machine works but the one built on our build machine does not work. I have very little control on that app and can not debug it, I can only see the output of it. Is there any way to check the differences of the dlls? I have used reflector, but it only shows limited info like classes and methods.
I also tried building it on other machines with vs2005, xps can create correctly, server 2008 and win7 can not.
could you guys help me with it?  any help would be appreciated. If I was not clear, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: define: "does not work"; what *exactly* happens? ideally, copying the exact error text

Comment: *************update: after many test, I found the problem has something to do with perforce or vs 2005 or both of them. I copy the project to another place and the built dll works, that happens on many machines that did not work. any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Marc. relating to "define: does not work" , I really can not see why it does not work, all I can see is the result of the calling app.

Comment: then the first thing to do is add debugging or logging so that you *can* see what happens; we aren't psychic. Most times, a very detailed and illuminating error message will be constructed telling you what went wrong...

Comment: it seems this forum does not allow us to chat? will this comment be deleted? just out of curiosity

Comment: I deleted the two messages that became obsolete when you edited your "update" comment; purely to reduce noise

Comment: yeah, if I'm asked about this question, I'd give similar answer. this question is not a good one. however, I have no choice, no debugging info is available. all I can do is try to find a magic to make the dll work. At least, I found how to create a working dll on our build machine.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?  I clicked on the link and found out I do not have enough reputation, I'm wondering what would happen if this discussion is moved to chat?

Comment: a room would be be created on chat.stackexchange.com, bringing in the key points from the discussion here so far; that chat is far more interactive

Comment: But: rather than concluding "no debugging info is available"; ***change*** that code to ***make*** the information you need available

Comment: it seems I have 12 reputation to go?

Comment: this app is too big for me, although I can get the source code. I don't think I can compile it successfully or even find out the related code now. our dll only implements it's interfaces. it's weird the problem has something to do with perfoce's source control.or this is an issue with vs 2005. any thing I can do to check the content of dll? I mean on a low level? I guess some info are not copied to the dll.

Comment: To work around, I copy the files of the project to another place and do compile. Don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn-t tell us the error-symptoms of "does not work" here is my guess formulated as a question:

Does your dll reference other dlls that are installed in global-assembly-cache? do all build machines have the same version of the gac-dll installed?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can only check if the dll works by checking a log. the referenced dlls are located in a directory of my project and will be copied to destiny directory.